# ASP. NET: "Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. Must declare the scalar variable "@ID"."

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, error-handling

I'm writing the following code to update and delete from a SQL Server.
I received the following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".".

The code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Statutory_JEs]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Statutory_JEs] SET [GL Account] = @GLAccount, [IFRS S-Section] = @IFRSSSection, [Trading Partner] = @TradingPartner, [Debit] = @Debit, [Credit] = @Credit, [Description] = @Description, [JE Type] = @JEType, [Reversal next year] = @ReversalNextYear,[Impact on revenue] = @ImpactOnRevenue, [Year] = @Year, [Company Code] = @CompanyCode, [Amount] = @Amount, [Functional Area] = @FunctionalArea, [JE purpose] = @JEPurpose, [Cycle] = @Cycle WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Statutory_JEs] WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GLAccount" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IFRSSSection" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TradingPartner" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Debit" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Credit" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JEType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ReversalNextYear" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ImpactOnRevenue" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyCode" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FunctionalArea" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JEPurpose" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cycle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What is causing the error message?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: when do you get that error?

Comment: put your id asp:parameter after Year

Comment: Hi, I receive this error when trying to update item.

Comment: I places the id asp:parameter after Year and still receive the same error message...